# \bigoplus, \prod, etc. with hats

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, unicode-math, accents

I would like to have big operators like `\bigoplus`, `\prod`, etc. with hats. A first approximation is the following code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\compdirsum}{\widehat{\bigoplus}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\restprod}{\widehat{\prod}}

\begin{document}

\(
\displaystyle
\compdirsum_{i \in I} V_i \to \restprod_{i \in I} V_i
\)

\bigskip

\(
\compdirsum_{i \in I} V_i \to \restprod_{i \in I} V_i
\)


\end{document}
```

However the hat is not centered and not «wide»:

[image]

How can this be fixed?